# How to save the code and the formatting properties of ace editor to the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ace-editor

The value in the editor is formatted only on the client side but when the value is sent to the database it is saved without the formatting.
How to save both the code and the formatting properties so that they both can be retrieved during display of the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Are you using raw action? If not, then read it.

I was using another editor (probably codemirror) and I saved the text in it to database in `<pre> </pre>` tag and then it would save as a string of html but later render properly too. Go through documentation of ace-editor. It must have a similar solution.

`pre` tag gives me this here:

**Gems for ace-editor:**

gem 'jquery-ace-rails'
gem 'ace-rails-ap'